Best practice for using Conan 2 with Cmake and multiple profiles
I am working on a project where we use cmake as build tool and conan (2.7.1) as dependency manager. This has so far worked out quite nicely, but there are some questions.
When Conan 2 was released we made the migration from Conan 1, and I think the biggest pet-peeve that we currently have is that from a 1-step-build process we had to move to a 2-step-build process, i.e. assuming there are some changes in you conanfile.py
cmake --build --preset custom-preset

we are now at
conan install conanfile.py -pr:a=my_profile --build="missing" -of=CONAN_ARTIFACTS_FOLDER
cmake --build --preset custom-preset

What complicates this even further is that we have people who develop on Windows and on Linux, meaning that they need different profiles, depending on what OS they are using. Previously this all could be encapsulated in the CMakeLists.txt, where as now everybody needs to make sure they pass the correct paths, and flags to conan (which has turned out to be quite error prone).
Now there are some ideas floating around of writing build scripts, i.e. a python/bash script that will detect the OS, etc. and make sure you call conan with the right arguments. So my questions boil down to:

Is there a better way to move forward in this situation?
Is it possible to somehow set on a project level settings like the output-folder or the build behavior (i.e. "missing", "*", "specific_package")?


For multiple profiles, you could use the conan command config to share/install you company profiles, the build policy you can include to your profile directly. To avoid that command line, you could use Conan extensions to create a custom command: https://docs.conan.io/2/reference/extensions/custom_commands.html

Because you were using the cmake-conan integration in Conan 1, and you dropped it in Conan 2? There is a new cmake-conan integration for Conan 2, have you checked it? Feel free to submit a ticket to https://github.com/conan-io/conan or https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan for further discussion with the maintainers.

@uilianries Thanks for the hint. I didnt know there was something like custom commands. Im currently trying to write one and struggling a bit with the ConanAPI (i.e. with conan_api.install.install_binaries)... What is the best place to get some help? Github issue or stackoverflow?

@drodri Is it possible to run custom conan commands with the cmake-conan extension?

How would that be possible. The cmake-conan extension use case is precisely not having to run commands, and get CMake to call conan install automatically, but that happens only when the first find_package() is found. You can implement the conan_provider.cmake that you want for cmake-conan and add there other calls, but it sounds it defeats the purpose of cmake-conan which is to call "conan install" transparently.
